# Push notification badge doesn't update with Urban Airship

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

As per the Urban Airship document, I have added below code on `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method for autobadge update but it is not working. Please help me for proper coding to **UA auto badge update**.

**Code:**

```
[[UAirship push] setAutobadgeEnabled:YES];
[[UAirship push] resetBadge];//zero badge
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit as to the behavior you are experiencing please?  EG; is the badge not incrementing properly?  Is the badge not resetting to zero?  Also, according to the documentation you need to call those methods in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, applicationDidBecomeActive, and application:didReceiveRemoteNotification.

Comment: I have called this methods in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions . Also badge do not appear and incrementing properly.